# How to visit www.google.com in Ubuntu with Shadowsocks

Tags: ubuntu, socks-proxy

I'm Chinese and I'm new to Ubuntu. I use [Shadowsocks](https://shadowsocks.org/en/index.html) to visit www.google.com in Windows, but I've found it hard to visit Google with [Shadowsocks-Qt5](https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks-qt5) in Ubuntu. There is little refrence about it on the Internet, and I have tried some different methods, but they didn't work for/cannot find an Autoproxy. Does anybody have experience in visiting www.google.com in Ubuntu?

Comment: Maybe edit the question title to make it clearer that you can't just use wwww.google.com in your browser like people in the Western world.

Comment: @xenoid please understand that in China there are a lot of online restrictions. So, the author's question is more about bypassing these restrictions than a regular browsing.

Comment: Yes, I know... but the bypass is the real question, and nothing hints at it in the title (and I assume Google is just an example...). Of course if the question has an answer here SO could also become blacklisted :)